# Media queries not working inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, media-queries

I have in a webpage which is responsive. It makes use of media queries.

But the same page loaded in an iframe is not working.

For example, consider to my webpage, I have given background color as red when the screen-width is less than 640px.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 640px) {

    .header-text {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

So when I load that window in a new tab and make the browser width less than 640px, background color becomes red.

But the same window when loaded in an iframe of 320*480 dimensions does not have background color red.

How to make media queries work in an iframe?

Comment: Set viewport in the parent windows. Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20838525/5016546

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try it this way, instead of `device` just target the `width`

Change

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 640px) {
```

to

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {
```

Also, it is more advised to target both *min* and *max* view-port width if you want to avoid considering order of media query declarations in your style-sheet

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    .header-text {
       background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's works for me with "max-device-width" but not with "max-width". With "max-width" it's the size of the iframe that counts.

Answer (score 20):

Include the meta bellow into the HTML which loads your iframe and it should work, at least on android devices.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: be aware though that to make it work on iOS, you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083462/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-be-responsive-in-ios-safari

Comment: Yeah, that problem occurred to me when I didn't put this in the head of the page that hosted the problematic iframe. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

I ended up having to target the iframes width. (May not work in all situations)
But what i did was make the iframe 100% width and then it would resize with the window, so all i did was target the px of the iframe instead of the window

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue i had, where media queries were not working as expected, was the empty src value on the iframe.

I had a sandboxed iframe to preview email templates inside another page. I used javascript injection to fill the iframe's html content after getting the html data with an ajax call to a service.

The solution for me was to create an empty html file, set this to the iframe src and then update the content with javascript.

Code on my page:

```html
<iframe src="/myfolder/dummy.html"></iframe>
```

Code for the iframe src:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="corrects media queries fails of email template previews" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the *iframe* attributes: Make sure that the *iframe* is not blocking styles from being loaded. Check the **sandbox** and allow attributes to see if they are restricting styles from being loaded.

Your iframe could look like that:

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-downloads allow-presentation" scrolling="auto" >
</iframe>
```