# Need to make html page responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Need to make theresponsive layout. I added meta viewpor, but still no luck. Or zoom it out according to screen dimensions to disable usage of horizontal scrollbar.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</head>
<body>

<div class='myIframe'>
<iframe height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="466" src="EXAMPLE_WEBSITE"></iframe>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to utilize breakpoints through CSS Media Queries. Please read through Mozilla's [documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }
```

This tells the browser to render the styles for the page when the minimum width of the viewport is met, which would be 700px.

You should be building with a mobile first approach. Your first stylesheet should reflect this. You will then gradually build up to greater displays.

Remember to use Relative units with Responsive Web Design.

Comment: can i implement media queries when i use iframe ?

Comment: @FarhadMammadli Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227214/media-queries-not-working-inside-an-iframe

Comment: thank you, now i need this webpage to fit or zoom out according to screen dimensions