# Targeting parent page of iframe with media query

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe that is going to be implemented in various pages. I'm trying to add CSS media queries inside of it, so that it works differently on different devices.
But the CSS media queries get the iframe's width, not the actual page.
Is there a way to do this with CSS and not Javascript?

The iframe is coming from the same domain, and on desktop, it should have a fixed width, while on mobile i'm trying to set it a fluid width.

So far I tried using normal media queries like:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    //css here
}
```

But this returns always true because the iframe is < 768px;

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: is the iframe coming from a site you own or is it an iframe like a youtube one where it's coming from an external source?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227214/media-queries-not-working-inside-an-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media queries not working inside an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227214/media-queries-not-working-inside-an-iframe)

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: You can't target the page _inside_ the iframe with a CSS rule that is on the same page as the iframe itself

Answer (score -1):

Use @media only screen and (max-device-width:768)

Comment: device-width media queries are being deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width