# Third party iframe inline style change

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I need to change third party `iframe` inline style. How to do this please let me know.

3rd party video player to display our site via `iframe`. It's working fine in normal view but responsive it's not display properly.

```
<iframe src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" id="" name="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I need to change the position & width only responsive how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media queries not working inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227214/media-queries-not-working-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via jquery.

Please use `$(window).width()` method to get width of you device and based on condition you can apply inline css to your iframe on document ready.
for ex-

```
var width = $(window).width();

if(width >= 1080) {
    $("iframe").css("width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;");
} 

else if(width >= 800 ) {
    $("iframe").css("width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;");
} 

else if(width >= 400 ) { // for mobile devices
    $("iframe").css("width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;");
} 

else if(width >= 300 ) { // for mobile devices
    $("iframe").css("width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {//android and ios
iframe {
   //css here
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {//for tablet devices
iframe {
   //css here
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {//for medium scale devices
iframe {
   //css here
}
}
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {//for desktops and laptops
iframe {
   //css here
}
}
```

make sure the following meta tag is in  in order the responsive to work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```