# Get mobile version in iframe

Tags: iframe, mobile, hyperlink

I have an iframe on my website and on the PC is everything fine. But when I open the site on my mobile phone I get the "mobile" site but the iframe parts are still like on the PC. 
The iframes are just links to a big site that has an own mobile version and when I open this site on my mobile phone i get the mobile version, but not when its linked in my iframe.
I want that it change in the iframe.
I tried some stuff but it doesn't work.
Do you have some tips?
max

Comment: How big is the iframe on mobile? Please show some code.

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.eventbrite.de/myEvent" name="SELFHTML_in_a_box" width="100%" height="1420" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

For others coming here via Google:

You have to set the viewport in the parent as explained in [iFrame and media query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158682/iframe-and-media-query-issue/20838525#20838525)