# How to apply bootstrap responsive classes inside iframe based on window size and not iframe size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an iframe inside a wrapper. The wrapper is of width=350px and height=450px. The iframe takes the height and width of this wrapper.

My problem is when I use bootstrap's utility class eg. hidden-xs, they are getting applied even on desktop. Is there any way these responsiveness styles would actually apply based on window size and not iframe size. The CSS is loaded inside iframe.

I tried approach as per [iFrame and media query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158682/iframe-and-media-query-issue) but it did not seem to work for me.

Comment: Media queries are based on the viewport, and for the content inside the iframe, the iframe _is_ the viewport. What you want is currently not possible. _Element media queries_ have been proposed by several people, but there is no implementation of that yet.

Comment: Thank you. That explains, I will look into other approaches. Having my own CSS class and defining styles with device-width(max-device-width) instead of width will work but does it sound like good approach?

Answer (score 0):

First,

since iFrame is just a window that displays external HTML files, it means that the iframe itself is a window/ browser screen. So you have to first make it responsive:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/

After that you must apply the bootstrap classes or whatever to the external html file that is being displayed in the iframe.
In other words 
create another html file, 
link the bootstrap,
design the html the way you want it to be, then display it on iframe.

I did the same for my site, it's not done yet, but take a look to get an idea.

http://urbanphenomena.net/shukri/#page3

And If you don't want any changes of the iframe...try to add the iframe outside of a div, class or whatever so the class's CSS doesn't effect the iframe

Comment: iframe is indeed the viewport for the external HTML file but I am not sure the question was fully understood by you. The iframe content is responsive, just not the way I want it to be. Thank you for your inputs, the comment below question answers it.